# Python function wihich takes a list of values and returns how many strings that list contains at the top level

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write function to print out how many strings in a given list with a while loop.

I already made with using for loop it's print out 6 that is correct but when ı try to do with a while loop ı can't see any print there are nothing printed no errors.

```
def count_strings(items):
    i = 0
    while i < len(items):
        if(type(items) == str):
            i += 1

    return i       


t =  ['apple', 55, 1.2, 'banana', lambda a: a, 'pear', None, 'cherry', """Hello world!""", -2, '''The Who''', ("a", 5), [("a", "5"), ("b", 3)]]

print(count_strings(t))
```

Comment: You're only advancing to the next object in the list if the current object is a string

Comment: Try `if isinstance(items[i], str)` instead of `if(type(items)==str)`

Comment: You meant `if type(items[i]) == str`

Comment: thank you.. guys :) @Sweeper answered what ı want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `i` *both* as the loop variable *and* the count for strings. You should use different variables. Also, `type(items)` is always `list`. You should check `type(items[i])`.

```
def count_strings(items):
    i = 0
    count = 0
    while i < len(items):
        if type(items[i]) == str:
            count += 1
        i += 1

    return count
```

If while loops are not a requirement, you can do this with list comprehension and `sum`:

```
sum([1 if type(x) == str else 0 for x in items])
```

Comment: @Sweeper your answer print out 13 ı need 6. and ı already do with for loop. ı need while loop to print out 6

Comment: My answer prints out 6 though. What code did you run? @canilgu

Comment: @Sweeper thank you so much.. ı'm learning faster with this website and your attention :)

Answer (score 0):

Another take for those who like one-liners

```
sum((type(element)==str for element in items))
```

Comparison `==` returns a boolean, which can be treated as `1` and thus summed.
Outer parentheses are for the `sum()` built-in function.
The inner parentheses form a *generator comprehension*. It's like a list comprehension, but does not create the whole thing in memory at once.

Comment: Thanks for this shortcut :)